# How to wait for form to draw before calling async task?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a master-details form where the master and details properties are placed into 2 separate table layouts. The details layout is initially hidden.

I load a record and display the master properties (using a bindingsource).

I then click a button to show the details layout. In doing so, I also get the details asynchronously, as follows:

```
private void layoutDetails_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetDetails();
}

private async void GetDetails()
{
    IEnumerable<OrderDetails> details = null;

    await Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        details = orderRequest.GetDetails(order.Id);
    });

   bindingSourceDetails.DataSource = details;
}
```

However, the form is not given enough time to show the details layout completely before the UI freezes momentarily to populate the listview.

The form itself is completely shown as the master properties are displayed well after the form has loaded (user selected a record to load). Then user then clicks the button to switch to the details table layout, and it is here that the listview somehow freezes momentarily whilst the details rows are retrieved and then the listview docks within the table layout.

Shouldn't the above solve the problem? Or is the problem caused when binding the `details` object to the bindingsource?

Comment: winforms or wpf? winforms has a "Shown" event, at that point everythings done

Comment: You should never do `async void` unless you are writing a function for a event handler. It is a bad habit to get in to. Also, you should not be mixing async/await with `ContinueWith`.

Comment: have you tried `your_control.SuspendLayout();` / populate datatable / `your_control.ResumeLayout();` ?

Comment: Side note: Ivan-Mark, could you tell why you are mixing await and ContinueWith? I've seen it done in many questions (sometimes with addition of Threads and Task.Run) and generally can't get my head around what authors expect to happen... `await` alone is hard to reason about for me... Is there some article/answer encouraging or explaining such complicated code?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, it looks like he was trying to impose an artificial delay to give the form enough time to draw.

Comment: @JBC That doesn't explain why he wouldn't use *either* `ContinueWith` *or* `await`, rather than both.

Comment: So the list has so many items that redrawing looks ugly? Call DoEvents before binding to make the UI draw once. It's not perfect but it will look much better already.

Comment: You can replace the ContinueWith with `await Task.Delay(100); var details = await Task.Run(() => orderRequest.GetDetails(order.Id));` but that's not the point of the question.